# Refactor to fix architectural error

Tags: android, multithreading, android-looper

In a sort-of-working application I see this monstrous code:

```
class SomeUglyClass extends Thread {
    ArrayList<SomeData> someDataStructure = new ArrayList<SomeData>();
    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        // a lot
        // writing to someDataStructure
    }
    public void run() {
        int some_count, ...;
        while(true) {
            // a lot
            // r/w access to someDataStructure

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1, 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }               
        }
    } // end of run(), total 500 lines of code
} // end of SomeUglyClass, total 4K lines of code
```

Maybe you already see the problems with this code. If not, here they are:

1. `mHandler` is attached to the UI thread (because it is created by the thread that loads the class, which is the main thread)
2. there's no looper (which is fact is ***the bug***)
3. the thread wastes CPU time and drains the battery
4. `someDataStructure` is not thread-safe, but synchronizing elementary access operations will not help; synchronizing large blocks of code in a endless loop will likely block the guarded resource and make it unavailable for other threads; finally, it is not only `someDataStructure`, the whole class is based on the assumption that only one thread can run its code.
5. I cannot just add the looper, because the endless loop in `run()` has to be run, while `Looper.loop();` also is an infinite loop. One thread cannot run two infinite loops.

Despite this epic architectural fail, the code is really doing something, it cannot be re-written at once, it is 4K lines of code, and often I can only guess what the code really does.

I need to refactor it. It should be a sequence of small steps preserving the functionality.

***How do I refactor this terrific code?***

Answer (score 1):

You should try [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): try first to divide the whole class into many smallest one, each one responsible for doing/dealing with exactly one thing.

You may have something for data Access (read/write data), service (isolated business logic), and the UI. You may use event bus to decouple between objects (consider [otto](https://github.com/square/otto)) and may be dependency injection (consider [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger)).

This process of separation will help you understand what each piece of code is doing and also the dependencies between the different parts, thus making writing unit/integration tests much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add lots of tests, use version control and then work as slowly as you need to.

Comment: Then the same thing I said, but work as fast as you can?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st step has been to change:

```
    public void run() {
        int some_count, ...;
        while(true) {
            // a lot
            // r/w access to someDataStructure

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1, 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }               
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new MyHandler();
        mHandler.post(run_step);
        Looper.loop();
    }

    Runnable run_step = new Runnable() {
        int some_count, ...;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //while(true) {
                // a lot
                // r/w access to someDataStructure

                mIntoThreadHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
            //}
        }
    }
```

This preserves the functionality but still wastes CPU time. The urgent bug has been fixed, and the issue has been closed; I could not sell *"must refactor to kill monstrous code"* to my management, but I could sell *"this can work faster if I refactor,"* so a new separate issue has been opened. UGH!

PS no chance to sell *"lots of tests"*.